# Insert multiple array values as integers - PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is probably very simple to accomplish, but I can't seem to get it. I have an array `$this->shippingLocations` which returns the following:

```
var_dump($this->shippingLocations);
array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "14" [1]=> string(1) "5" [2]=> string(1) "1" }
```

I want to insert the above values in a mysql table. Each on its own row using mysqli prepared statements but as integers. So I convert the values into integers.

```
foreach($this->shippingLocation as $key => $val) {
  $shipArray[$key] = (int)$val;
}
```

Which gives the follwing:

```
var_dump($shipArray);
array(3) { [0]=> int(14) [1]=> int(5) [2]=> int(1) }
```

Then get number of items in array

```
$addCountry = count($shipArray);
```

And run query for each of them.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $addCountry; $i++) {

      $data = array (
      "item_id" => $lastItemID,
      "country_id" => $shipArray[$i]
  );
 // types for bind_param, table name and array(keys are table columns and values are data for columns) which are passed to a working insert function
  $db->insert('ii', 'countries_ship', $data);

  }
```

The notice I get is Undefined offset: 1 .. .2 ... 3 depending on how many items are in the array.

Comment: Please post the code behind the `$db->insert()` method.  It must be calling `prepare()/execute()` in there, but I'd like to see how. The `str_repeat()` looks incorrect, because `mysqli::bind_param()`'s first argument is a single string with no whitespace, as in `iiiiiiiis` for 8 ints and a string.  The PHP type of those as integer vs string doesn't really matter to MySQLi. As long as they are bound with `i`, it's fine - you don't need to cast them.

Comment: I notice also here that you are overwriting `$shipArray` in the for loop.   `$shipArray = array ('item_id' => $lastItemID...)`. You must either intend to use a different variable, or to append to `$shipArray`. It isn't obvious to me which yet.

Comment: I would like to append to $shipArray ... how do I do that? I want `$shipArray` to have the exact keys and values but values should be integers.

Comment: Using the `[]` append syntax: `$ahipArray[] = array('item_id' => $lastItemID....)`

Comment: so `$shipArray` being this `array(3) { [0]=> int(14) [1]=> int(5) [2]=> int(1) }` is not right? The values are there, and they're integers.

Comment: I'm talking about your later use of the same variable `$shipArray`, in the `for` loop near the bottom of your post. There, you are _assigning_ `$shipArray = array(...)` while also in the same assignment trying to reference `$shipArray[$i]`.  You have a naming conflict. Thus the undefined offset 1,2,3 -- after the first index in the loop `[0]`, $shipArray is no longer a multi-item array. It has been overwritten to a single associative array.

Comment: That makes sense. I missed that one, thank you. The offset notices are gone now. I've edited my question a bit also ... one thing that's still bugging me is that even if in the array there are 2,3,4 or more items, there is only one row being inserted in the table. Shouldn't that for loop add multiple rows where `item_id` will be the same but only the `country_id` changes?

Comment: Nevermind, got it to work. Had to restructure the table a bit. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: You should post an answer detailing how you solved it and mark it as the answer so this appears completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting working code. My only problem was the duplicate name in the for statement.

```
//$this->shippingLocations is an array with string values

//changing string to array for all values
foreach($this->shippingLocation as $key => $val) {
  $shipArray[$key] = (int)$val;
}

//counting items in new array
$addCountry = count($shipArray);

//add each item in `countries_ship` table
for ($i = 0; $i < $addCountry; $i++) {

  //creating array for mysql query
  $data = array (
  "item_id" => $lastItemID,
  "country_id" => $shipArray[$i]
);

//insert into table
$db->insert('ii', 'countries_ship', $data);

}
```